# How to use a timing on a picture's source on beamer

Tags: beamer, pause, source

I have a slide with two columns: an itemize with pauses, and an overprint with pictures. They were perfect until I decided to insert the picture's source on the bottom. So now I have the source since the beginning and the picture showing after. 
I would like the source to appear with the picture and go away at the same time. Here goes the code:

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Tratamento: Retorno do andar voluntário}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Magnetoterapia
        \item<3-> Cinesioterapia
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm}

    \begin{overprint}
        \includegraphics<2>[width=4cm]{dante}
        \hspace*{17pt}\hbox{\scriptsize Fonte:\thinspace{\small\itshape Arquivo pessoal}}
    \end{overprint}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

The idea is that for each item I show a picture and it's source. I've tried moving around the box command the `<2>` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following code solve your problem?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Tratamento: Retorno do andar voluntário}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Magnetoterapia
        \item<3-> Cinesioterapia
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm}

    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        \includegraphics<2>[width=4cm]{example-image}
        \hspace*{17pt}\hbox{\scriptsize Fonte:\thinspace{\small\itshape Arquivo pessoal}}
    \end{onlyenv}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You're welcome! But I am wondering why out of a sudden so many people use `overprint`. I cannot remember having seen a question using it, but this last week, there had been at least 3 questions about it.

Comment: I found the command on a beamer model I found some time ago on the internet and used for mine.
I use latex for some time now, but it's my second beamer file, and the first one was quite simple